# ThreadPoolExecutor getActiveCount() is 1 but getQueue returns empty queue, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool, executorservice

`ThreadPoolExecutor getActiveCount()` is 1 but `getQueue` returns empty queue, why?

I have a executor which type is ThreadPoolExecutor.

I call getActiveCount() and got 1,

but when I call getQueue.size(), it is 0.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getQueue%28%29

My code is something like this.

```
  System.out.println(taskExecutor.getActiveCount());
  System.out.println(taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size());
```

So I am confused, why these 2 are not same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the javadocs (emphasis mine)

`getActiveCount()`: Returns the **approximate** number of threads that are **actively** executing tasks.

`getQueue()`: Returns the task **queue** used by this executor.

Now the explanation... `getQueue()` returns the queue where tasks are **waiting** to be executed, once a task is ready to be executed, it is taken from the queue and given to a thread. Also, keep in mind that `getActive()` returns an approximation and should not be used in any kind of logic.

So there are 2 possible answers to your question. There's one task running... or getActive() is returning an approximation. Whatever is the case, there are no tasks waiting to be executed.